# Spring batch 2.4.1 + Wildfly 20 final - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BLOCK_UNSAFE_POLYMORPHIC_BASE_TYPES

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am trying to execute Spring batch application on Wildfly server 20 final but I get the following error,

The same code works fine if i use builtin tomcat server.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BLOCK_UNSAFE_POLYMORPHIC_BASE_TYPES
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.<init>(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:192)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784)
```

Comment: I had the same issue deploying in Weblogic. Fixed by adding ` <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>`  to weblogic.xml `<prefer-application-packages>` section

Answer (score 6):

I get this problem too, it looks like springbatch 4.3.0 has introduced a dependency on jackson databind 2.11.

Here's the spring commit: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/commit/9a79b4572d0aa4bec38fe90957c850920b7f9cea

And the databind commit:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/fa402574f99daa10410682160365df0867abe4d4

-> So need to downgrade to 4.2.x or upgrade jackson to 2.11

(Updated: Commit was introduced in springbatch 4.3.0, not 4.3.1)

Comment: You're the best! I was able to get to spring boot starters 2.2.0, but spring-batch-core was only 4.2.0.RELEASE and I wanted 4.2.3.RELEASE, but it failed for this same NoSuchFieldError (spring 2.2.0 uses jackson-databind 2.10.0). 2.11.0 got it to work, thanks!